# Add query string to all requests of NSURLSession

Tags: ios, iphone, nsurlsession

How to add query string to every url request of NSURLSession. All request will have the same query string.

How to append this?

Comment: Hello Dev, Please let us know what have to tried so far

Answer (score 0):

Below is the way to send the string to every request URL

```
NSString *stringURL=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@",baseUrl,@"/API/URL/",your parameter];

// Allocate and initialize an NSURLConnection with the given request and delegate. The asynchronous URL load process is started as part of this method.

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:stringURL] cachePolicy:NSURLCacheStorageNotAllowed timeoutInterval:300];
```